# Convert string to image/tiff

Tags: android

I need to convert a TextView of base64 code to an image

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
tv.buildDrawingCache();
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
img.setImageBitmap(tv.getDrawingCache());
```

This does not work :/
Can someone help me?

Comment: I see no base64.

Comment: the code is inside tv

Comment: If you do not supply the base64 string than we cannot give help of course. And why did you put the string in a textview? What sense does that make? Does it look nice those chacters?

Comment: ready, check the changes

Comment: Nkt enough. Define the string in your code and assign it to the textview to begin with. At the moment there is no connection with the textview.

Comment: that's the problem, I want to convert that chain to image.

Comment: What is a chain?

Comment: the string code, sorry.

Comment: Wel then start with defining a string which contains that base64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// add dependency in gradle 
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

if (theCaptchaBase64 != null) {
            byte[] image_data_bytes = Base64.decode(theCaptchaBase64, Base64.NO_WRAP);
            String Image_Data_str = null;
            try {
                Image_Data_str = new String(image_data_bytes, "UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String imageFileExt = ".jpg";
            if (Image_Data_str != null && Image_Data_str.contains("png")) {
                imageFileExt = ".png";
            }


            long msTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Date dt = new Date(msTime);
            String format = "yyMMddHHmmssSSS";
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US);
            String captchaFileName = String.format("Captcha" + "_%s", sdf.format(dt).toString());
            //String captchaFileName = "Captcha";
            captchaFileName = captchaFileName + imageFileExt;

            String imageSaveFolderPath = TempFolderPath + "/" + captchaFileName;

            String imgPath = writeImageBytesOnSdCard(this, imageSaveFolderPath, Image_Data_str);

            loadImageWithGlide(this,ImageViiew,imgPath);
        }


         public static void loadImageWithGlide(Context theCtx, ImageView theImageView, String theUrl) {
        // skipMemoryCache, because it load the same image because URL not change.
        Glide.with(theCtx)
                .load(theUrl)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                .skipMemoryCache(true)
                .into(theImageView);

        //Glide.with(mContext).load(imagePath).into(myHolder.mImageViewUserImage);
    }


        public static String writeImageBytesOnSdCard(Activity theActivity, String theCustomImagePath, String theCustomImageData) {
        String imagePath = theCustomImagePath;
        String temp[] = theCustomImageData.split("\\,");
        if (temp[0].contains("data:image/png")) {
            imagePath = getImagePath(imagePath, "png");
        } else {
            imagePath = getImagePath(imagePath, "jpg");
        }
        byte[] data = null;
        try {
            //data=myImageData1.getBytes("UTF-8");
            data = Base64.decode(temp[1], Base64.DEFAULT);
            FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(imagePath), false);
            InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);

            OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream);
            byte[] loginBuffer = new byte[1024];
            int byteRead = 0;
            while ((byteRead = in.read(loginBuffer)) != -1) {
                out.write(loginBuffer, 0, byteRead);
            }
            out.close();
            if (outputStream != null) {
                try {
                    outputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            // code for sending a notification to the media scanner
            updateMedia(theActivity, imagePath);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            imagePath = "";
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            imagePath = "";
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return imagePath;
    }

    public static String getImagePath(String theExportImagePath, String theRequiredExt) {
        File f = new File(theExportImagePath);
        String fileName = f.getName();

        String parent = f.getParent();
        String filename_Without_Ext = fileName;

        int dotposition = fileName.lastIndexOf(".");

        if (dotposition != -1)
            filename_Without_Ext = fileName.substring(0, dotposition);

        return parent + "/" + filename_Without_Ext + "." + theRequiredExt;
    }

    public static void updateMedia(final Activity theActivity, String filepath) {
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(theActivity.getApplicationContext(), new String[]{filepath}, null, null);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example (assume your text is correct) :

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

String base64String = tv.getText();
String base64Image = base64String.split(",")[1];

byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(base64Image, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);

img.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
```